# Why is my router setup page blocked by my ISP?

Tags: networking, router

I have a Cisco DPC2320 and I was trying to access the setup page to setup port forwarding but I couldn't access the page(192.168.0.1) due to "The connection was reset error". But I can ping it.

And when I unplugged the cable from the router i could access the page.
So my question is why is my ISP blocking my setup page and is there a way for me to access it without unplugging the cable.I did confirm my router ip address by using

```
route -n
```

Output:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlan0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlan0
```

**EDIT**:Just found not even if i unplug i cant access the setup page. I have to reset the modem.Any ideas what to do?

Comment: It's not possible for your ISP to block traffic to a device within your own network.  They have no control over `192.168.0.1 ` that specific address does not exist outside of your network.

Comment: @Ramhound they why dose it work then I unplug the cable ?

Answer (score 1):

Your ISP can't block your private addresses on your own network. So it has to be an issue with your set up. IP blocks like 10.x.x.x, 192.168.x.x and a few others are reserved for private use behind NAT and are not routed in the public internet. That could be your first issue. If you try to access your routes setup page from the WAN side (where you plug in the cable coming from your ISP) you can't access it. Same goes for connecting via mobile internet services.

Another reason could be that the router only offers the config page on HTTPS or a specific port. Did you enable anything like this in the configuration? Also check the manual whether it mentions to connecting to https://192.168.0.1 or just http://192.168.0.1. Maybe there is also a port specified like this https://192.168.0.1:xxxxx. Maybe try to reset the device to factory defaults by method mentioned in the manual.

Last thing to check is whether you are on the same IP network as the router is. Is your interface, when connected to the router via cable, configured with a network address in the same block as the router is? So in your case, your computer should have a 1192.168.0.xxx adresse with a net mask of /24 (255.255.255.0). (Check if you disabled DHCP on your cable interface, that might also explain why WiFi works and cable does not)

Answer (score 0):

I had to turn off my VPN to access the router settings. Weird, I know, but the work laptop which had checkpoint vpn on was blocking access to the router settings.
2 hrs of cursing randomly turned vpn off and voilà! Could access the router settings.

Comment: If your laptop had a VPN to another network then it wouldn't know about your local network which is why it wasn't working. Not weird. You should 'Accept' your answer.